# Transaction is not getting signed while using glow wallet from solana-wallet-adapters

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, react

Signing using glow wallet is not working with @solana/wallet-adapter-react , I am getting the signature as `11111111111111111111111111111111111111`.

```
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
const { signTransaction } = useWallet();

const transaction = {} // Partially signed Solana versioned transaction
signTransaction(transaction)
const transactionId = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
  transaction.serialize(),
  {skipPreflight: true},
);
```

This implementation works well with Phantom, but not with Glow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `signTransaction` API does not, and never did guarantee that the transaction will be signed in-place. You must use its *return* value.

```
const signedTransaction = signTransaction(transaction);
const transactionId = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
  signedTransaction.serialize(),
  {skipPreflight: true},
);
```

Comment: For more on this common mistake, see: https://twitter.com/0xprof_lupin/status/1613252832525955073